# Как перевести строку java-формата ddMMyyyyHmmss в дату Oracle функцией to_date()?

Tags: oracle, дата, время, sql

Например, есть строка *0106201395810* (или *31052013155754*), которая подходит под формат `new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHmmss")`, т.е. в первом случае *1 июня 2013 года 9 часов 58 минут 10 секунд*. Вариант `to_date('0106201395810', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS')` не подходит потому что HH24 подразумевает два символа.

Comment: А что мешает выводить из Java человеческую дату с часами в формате 09, а не 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select to_date(substr('0106201395810',1,8)||substr('0'||substr('0106201395810',9),-6), 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS')
from dual